# Form field to be placed side by side

Tags: css, forms

I created a form for payment the fields are in vertical. What code can I add to this or the CSS in order to make them side by side?

```
[text name="Text Title"][text name="Full Name" required="required" ]

[text name="Phone Number"]
[datepicker name="Datepicker Title"]
[select name="State" options="Abia,Adamawa,Akwa Ibom,Anambra,Bauchi,Bayelsa,Benue,Borno,Cross River,Delta,Ebonyi,Edo,Ekiti,Enugu,FCT,Gombe,Imo,Jigawa,Kaduna,Kano,Katsina,Kebbi,Kogi,Kwara,Lagos,Nasarawa,Niger,Ogun,Ondo,Osun,Oyo,Plateau,Rivers,Sokoto,Taraba,Yobe,Zamfara"]
```

Comment: Have a look: [How To Create a Responsive Inline Form With CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_inline_form.asp)

Comment: It would be helpful to see your HTML code.